# Cypress/VueJS Selecting Element that is dynamically added after another action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I'm testing a feature where a button appears for the user to click AFTER they have taken another action.

Before taking the action I'm checking if the button exists:

```
cy.get('span')
    .contains('Select')
    .parent('button')
    .should('not.exist');
```

And after the action I'm trying to find that same button like this but it fails. Would anyone know how to do this in Cypress?

Here is my entire code:

```
cy.get('span')
    .contains('Select')
    .parent('button')
    .should('exist');
```

```
/* eslint-disable */

describe('Workgroup Switch', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('/login');
        cy.get('input[id="username"]').type('boss@example.com');
        cy.get('input[id="password"]').type('password');
        cy.get('button[id="login-button"]').click();
        cy.url().should('include', '/offers/workgroup');
    });

    it('switch workgroup', () => {
        cy.get('span')
            .contains('Select')
            .parent('button')
            .should('not.exist');

        cy.get('.v-overlay__scrim').click();

        cy.get('.text-h6')
            .contains('Workgroup #1')
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .click();

        cy.contains('Make this my default workgroup');

        cy.get('span')
            .contains('Select')
            .parent('button')
            .should('exist');
    });
});
```

Comment: have you checked that the button is really visible/present ? try to do a screenshot ? no animation occuring ?

Comment: The button is definitely there. Its hidden by a simple `v-if`

Comment: `v-if` remove the button from the DOM when condition is false. (not like `v-show`)

Comment: Have you used a timeout for this. In case it is taking more than 4 seconds to appear `.should('exist',{timeout: 5000})`

Comment: I was experimenting and just added a custom class to the button. I was then able to target it. Not sure why that is but seems to work for the timebeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the combined form of `contains()` to get the correct element.

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Select')
  .parent('button')
  .should('exist');
```

Doing it in two parts like this

```js
cy.get('span')
  .contains('Select')
```

Cypress finds the first span on the page and then repeatedly checks it's text for "Select", but it does not repeat the `cy.get('span')` part.